# Create views from tables with different number of columns mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to views in MySQL server.

I'm trying to create two VIEWS with "invoice_head" and "invoice_body", but in order to do that i need to get different keys from different tables (this tables have diferent number of columns).

This is the code that i'm trying to use:

```
CREATE VIEW invoice_head AS
SELECT
    date_order AS 'DATE OF ISSUE'
    FROM orders
UNION ALL
SELECT
    customer_name AS 'Client Name',
    customer_address AS 'Street adress', 
    customer_district AS 'District', 
    customer_country AS 'Portugal', 
    customer_zipcode AS 'ZIP Code'
    FROM customer;
```

but this code is giving me the error: The used SELECT statements have different number of columns.

And the tables i'm using are something like this (for example)

Customer Table (8 columns)

| customer_id | customer_name | customer_address | customer_district | (...) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | maria xxx | street xxx | lisbon | (...) |

Orders Table (9 columns)

| order_id | customer_id | product_id | date_order | (...) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 20 | 2020-12-15 | (...) |

The invoice_head is supposed to have information about the customer, the invoice_id, and the date of the order (invoice_date aka date_order).

Can someone tell me in what way is this possible to be made?
Is it impossible to do or I need to do something I'm not seeing?

Comment: It seems you want a **join**. You want to join the customer to the order, so as to show the complete order header data including customer information.

Comment: is it possible to use join in a view?

Comment: Yes, of course. The view contains a query. Whatever query you write, you can make it a view.

Comment: On a side note: You are using the wrong quotes. Use single quotes for string literals and double quotes (or backticks depending on your settings) for names. The best option is not to use any quotes for names at all, however, and just use names that need no quoting (e.g. `AS zip_code`).

Comment: Thank u! I'm now just struggling to do the "invoice_id" without get it from a table. I need to do something like "view index"? Right?

Comment: *do* the invoice ID? What is that supposed to mean? You are talking of an invoice, but select from the order table. Is there an invoice table you want to join, too, maybe?

Comment: I would like to generate an invoice with the existing tables, without having to create an "invoice" table. But I would like the view to have a column with "Invoice Number:" and the number be like: 0001...0002 etc. The only way I can see for that to work is to use the "order_id" as the "Invoice number", but I would like to have a different "number" for the "invoice number", is that possible?

Comment: This is a weird request. What would you even use this view for? If you want to generate numbers starting with 1 you can use an auto-increment column for this.

Comment: I must admit I hardly ever work with views. What would that be good for? To avoid some typing? I'd rather just select from the tables directly and write my queries as I want them. Views can be helpful to restrict access to columns and/or rows or hide complicated joins from the view user, but with a properly built database, joins are usually straight forward. And you seem to have something very particular in mind with your view, but I can't figure what that might be. Maybe you really want something very different from a view in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Someone in the comments helped me. I just needed to use the "Join" instead of "Select":

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `invoice_head`;
CREATE VIEW `invoice_head` AS
SELECT  date_order as `Date of issue`,
        customer_name AS `Client Name`,
        customer_address AS `Street adress`, 
        customer_district AS `District`, 
        customer_country AS `Country`, 
        customer_zipcode AS `ZIP Code`
FROM orders
join customer
    on orders.customer_id = customer.customer_id;
```